# Read all lines except commented ones, lines containing 'bind|swap|shm' from/etc/fstab and print the ones in them that are not mounted?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

Read all lines except commented ones, lines containing 'bind|swap|shm' from/etc/fstab and print the ones in them that are not mounted? I have tried the below and I was wondering if I could get a better shorter code.

```
mount_check()
{
fstb=$(cat /etc/fstab |egrep -vw 'bind|swap' |awk '$1 !~/#|^$/ {print $2}')
for i in ${fstb}
do
df -hPT | grep -wq ${i}
if [ $? -eq 1 ]
 then
 echo "The file system ${i} has an entry in /etc/fstab file but not mounted"
fi
done
}rc_mount_check=`mount_check |tee |wc -l`if [ $rc_mount_check -eq '0' ]
then
        echo -e "OK: All file systems listed in /etc/fstab are mounted"
        exit $OK
else
        echo -e "CRITICAL: Please verify and mount the file systems\n$(mount_check)\n"
        exit $CRITICAL
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Actual command which you are looking for is `findmnt`. Could you please try following.

```
awk '
!/bind|swap|shm/ && $1 !~/#|^$/{
  system("if [[ -n $(findmnt -m " $2 ") ]]; \
          then echo Mount " $2 " is mounted.;\
          else echo Mount " $2 " is NOT mounted.;\
          fi"\
  )
}
' /etc/fstab
```

OR in form of one-liner try following(in case you need it):

```
awk '!/bind|swap|shm/ && $1 !~/#|^$/ {system("if [[ -n $(findmnt -m " $2 ") ]]; then echo Mount " $2 " is mounted.;else echo Mount " $2 " is NOT mounted.;fi")}' /etc/fstab
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the currently accepted answer:

```
awk '
!/bind|swap|shm/ && $1 !~/#|^$/{
  system("if [[ -n $(findmnt -m " $2 ") ]]; \
          then echo Mount " $2 " is mounted.;\
          else echo Mount " $2 " is NOT mounted.;\
          fi"\
  )
}
' /etc/fstab
```

does what you want, you should actually do something like this (untested) instead:

```
mounts=( $(awk '!/bind|swap|shm/ && $1 !~/#|^$/ { print $2 }' /etc/fstab) )
for mount in "${mounts[@]}"; do
    if [[ -n $(findmnt -m "$mount") ]]
        then echo "Mount $mount is mounted."
        else echo "Mount $mount is NOT mounted."
    fi
done
```

i.e. don't call shell to call awk to call system to call shell to call findmnt. Just have shell 1) call awk to get whatever list of mounts that first awk line spits out and then 2) call findmnt on that list. That way you're not spawning subshells upon subshells and 5 layers deep for every mount.